# Intersection of multidimensional hashes in Perl

Tags: perl, hash

I am trying to determine the part of a nested hash that is not in common with another hash. For example:

```
my $p = {a => {b => 'b', c => 'c'}, d => 'd'};
my $q = {a => {c => 'c', f => 'f'}, e => 'e'};
```

I would like to have a function `hash_unique` that returns the part of `$q` that is not in `$p`:

```
my $r = hash_unique($q, $p);
```

It should give `$r = {a => {f => 'f'}, e => 'e'}`. Note: Only the keys of the hashes should be checked, difference in value is ignored.

Comment: What is the question, actually? Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a nice solution using [Hash::Diff](http://search.cpan.org/~bolav/Hash-Diff-0.005/lib/Hash/Diff.pm) :

```
use Data::Dump qw(dump);
use Hash::Diff qw(left_diff);

my $p={a=>{b=>'b',c=>'c'},d=>'d'};
my $q={a=>{c=>'c',f=>'f'},e=>'e'};
my $r=left_diff($q,$p);
dump($r);
```

gives me the correct solution:

```
{ a => { f => "f" }, e => "e" }
```